# How to produce landscape or portrait photo base on device orientation

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation

I reed this tutorial to create camera app - [1](https://github.com/appcoda/FullScreenCamera): https://www.appcoda.com/avfoundation-swift-guide/

When I rotate my device to landscape and would like to take a landscape photo, the photo is always portrait. I really have know idea how to fix it. I hope the photo could display landscape or portrait base on user's device orientation.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the device's current orientation. Convert that into the correct `videoOrientation`. Apply that to the session's output's connection. Capture the image.

Comment: See Apple's https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcam_building_a_camera_app